# Error when trying to add new words into WordSegment dictionary: module 'wordsegment' has no attribute 'bigram_counts'

Tags: python, nlp

I want to avoid word segment seperate 'new zealand' as two words 'new' and 'zealand' by adding the term into my dictionary.
I tried `ws.bigram_counts['new zealand'] = 1.08e9`  but received error

```
AttributeError: module 'wordsegment' has no attribute 'bigram_counts'
```

1.08e9 is the number of searches on google for 'new zealand'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ws.BIGRAMS['new zealand'] = 1.08e9`